# how to specify https protcol in SQLAlchemy > Presto connection?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, hive, sqlalchemy, presto

I'm trying to run Hive queries via Presto using SQLAlchemy. It uses LDAP authentication but I'm missing something in the connection string.

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

conn_string = 'presto://' + user + ':' + passw + '@' + host + ':' + port + db \
    + ", connect_args={'auth':LDAP}"
   
eng = create_engine(conn_string)
```

I'm getting an error that says:

```
Protocol must be https when passing a password
```

I've seen some discussion about this when searching but don't see a clear resolution. I've tried many combinations with and without the port, db, etc. Do you know how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The [`README` of PyHive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive#passing-session-configuration) contains this snippet:

```
create_engine(
    'presto://user@host:443/hive',
    connect_args={'protocol': 'https',
                  'session_props': {'query_max_run_time': '1234m'}}
)
```

It seems that all you need to do is add `'protocol': 'https'` to the connect_args.

Comment: I just noticed in that example they don't specify a password. Not sure how that could work. Anyway I did like that and now I get "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,"

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using a different library that worked:

```
import prestodb

conn=prestodb.dbapi.connect(
    host=host,
    port=port,
    user=user,
    catalog='db_name',
    schema='my_schema',
    http_scheme='https',
    auth=prestodb.auth.BasicAuthentication(user, passw)
)
```

Then I was able to retrieve the results and put into a dataframe. So no need for SQLAlchemy. It seems unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0):

from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
engine = create_engine('presto://username:password@vmwidpappprd.corp.net.com:8443/hive',
connect_args={'protocol': 'https', 'requests_kwargs': {'verify': False}})
db = engine.raw_connection()
s=engine.execute("SELECT * FROM idp_dim_prd.sales_territory")
print(s)
for r in s:
print(r)